# Help with .htaccess setup to hide WordPress Directory

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess

I have a WordPress site that is installed in a directory called cms.

I will be using a pure HTML page as my Home page, the inner pages will be using WordPress.

Let's call the website mysite.com

visiting mysite.com needs to show my plain html page.

The help I need is to hide the cms folder in the URL.

I have the following .htaccess file in my root

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cms/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cms/$1 
</IfModule>
```

And this .htaccess in side the cms directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /cms/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /cms/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I don't think I need to have both but that is the only way I've gotten the pages to show up without an error.

For example lets say I have a page called **MyPage**

With how I have things set now it is accessible at:

**mysite.com/MyPage** AND **mysite.com/cms/MyPage**

I need it to only be accessible at mysite.com/MyPage

While maintaining the ability to serve the static HTML page at mysite.com

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: have you considered using a page as the homepage with a page template? Or using `home.php` in your theme? Then you wouldn't need to have WP in a subfolder, and you wouldn't need a static HTML file

Comment: I would like to avoid having to do that if at all possible. Having the homepage completely outside of WordPress is preferable for the situation.

Comment: Keep in mind that copy pasting the static homepage into `home.php` gives you exactly the same result with no code changes, you'll have to provide more context of the situation, especially since HTAccess is a part of your question

Comment: If you think that is where my issues stem from I can try that approach. Having the homepage completely outside of the CMS is a request from the client, but I can work that out if necessary. I feel like what I'm trying to achieve in my OP should be possible however.